# Function variable becoming nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a strange problem in my objective C code. I am developing an application for iPhone (iOS 7 and above).

I have a function that is defined as given below

```
@interface SomeClassName : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *someArray;

@implementation SomeClassName
@synthesize someArray;

- (void) removeFromSomething:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    [sectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (((int)[sectionArray count]) == 0) {
        [self.someArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    }

}
```

The variable sectionArray always return a `Nil` even though self.someArray has elements and the indexPath.section points to an element that is within the self.someArray.

This magically worked when I did this..

```
@interface SomeClassName : NSObject 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *someArray;

@implementation SomeClassName
@synthesize someArray;

NSMutableArray *sectionArray;

- (void) removeFromSomething:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        sectionArray = [self.someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        [sectionArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if (((int)[sectionArray count]) == 0) {
            [self.someArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        }

    }
```

This was not happening until now (my project is almost complete and I have also tested in the device). This problem came very recently and not only in this function, this is happening throughout the application causing incorrect behaviour.

I'm new to iOS development and this is the first application that I'm planning to publish in AppStore. Any idea what is going wrong or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: iOS 9 ??? The latest iOS version is iOS 7.

Comment: He may know something we don´t know... Will iOS 9 support the toaster?

Comment: Sorry folks.. Just updated the version. Its iOS7.

Comment: There is **no** magic. Really work on understanding why one worked and not the other. Consider the scope (lifetime) of variables, this is just basic "C" language stuff.

Comment: Can you pls post the code where you declare self.someArray?

Comment: Edited the second code chunk with someArray declaration. Its the same both the code chunks.

Comment: There is no way to tell what's going on from the code you posted. Post the code that initializes and populates someArray. Then add an NSLog statement at the beginning of your removeFromSomething that logs your someArray and the indexPath that you are using to delete and object.

Comment: How are you detecting that sectionArray is nil?  How do you know that someArray exists *in this case*?

Comment: Hot Licks' questions are very important. Are you actually confirming that `someArray` exists in this method when it is executed?

Comment: I am using the debugger to detect that secionArray is nil and someArray has objects...

Comment: Use NSLog.  The debugger lies a lot.

Comment: @HotLicks you are correct. The debugger seems to lie a lot. When I displayed someArray and someArray.count it is displaying correct value. I am debugging it further for the incorrect behavior

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you confound `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray`. It is very likely that the element at `indexPath.section` is a plain array, not a mutable one. While the array holding the arrays can be mutable, the array elements are only mutable if you explicitly made them so.

Thus you assign an array to a mutable array variable. The compiler does not complain, because mutable array is a subclass of array. I do not think it is guaranteed behaviour that the mutable array variable will hold the non-mutable array anyway. Maybe that's why you get `nil`.

In any case, when you try to remove stuff from a non-mutable array (even if you put it into a variable of type `NSMutableArray`) it will certainly not work.

The way to create a mutable array from an array is

```
NSMutableArray *mutable = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nonMutableArray];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *mutable = nonMutableArray.mutableCopy;
```

You would have to copy the modified array back into the array (again as a non-mutable version).